MS Outlook Sortable User-defined Columns
In response to the question "How do I get rid of the "External" label in Outlook?", user Lilienthal posted a response on  Jan 20, 2023 by creating a custom column using the formula [From]. When you click the header, the error meesage "You cannot sort by this field" appears. Is it possible to make this column sortable?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In Outlook, custom fields may not be sortable by default. This is because they are often generated through specific formulas or functions that may not support sorting operations.
